# Ctypes access violation error

Tags: python, ctypes

I'a trying to port an old rfid library implemented in oldest VB to a python script.

here's the vb code:

```
dim hport as integer 
dim hreader as integer 
hport=FECOM_OpenPort("1") 
if hport>0 then 
   FECOM_SetPortPara(hport,"Baud","38400") 
   FECOM_SetPortPara(hport,"Frame","8E1") 
   hreader =FEISC_NewReader(hport)
   and so on
```

I am not absolute new to the ctypes thing, ok I tried this:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import *
feisc = ctypes.cdll.FeIsc
fecom = ctypes.cdll.FeCom
c_port = c_wchar('3')
#c_port = c_wchar('3')
hport = fecom.FECOM_OpenPort(c_port)
```

and got: 
OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x00000033

I read the dokumentation on cType datetyes handling but I can't see the right way

the descript of the functions:

```
int FECOM_OpenPort( char* cPortNr )
int FECOM_ClosePort( int iPortHnd )
int FECOM_GetPortPara( int iPortHnd, char* cPara, char* cValue )
int FECOM_SetPortPara( int iPortHnd, char* cPara, char* cValue )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c_wchar` is equivalent to C's `wchar_t` not `char*`, so `c_wchar('3')` is passing the ASCII value 0x0033 instead of a valid pointer to char, which matches the address of the access violation.

With `ctypes` it is best to be explicit about types by specifying the argument types and return type, then just pass a Python byte string for any *input* `char*` parameter (which really should be `const char*` to make this clear).  Output parameters require a writable string and should be allocated with `create_string_buffer()`.

```
from ctypes import *

fecom = CDLL('FeCom')

# int FECOM_OpenPort( char* cPortNr )
fecom.FECOM_OpenPort.argtypes = c_char_p,
fecom.FECOM_OpenPort.restype = c_int

# int FECOM_ClosePort( int iPortHnd )
fecom.FECOM_ClosePort.argtypes = c_int,
fecom.FECOM_ClosePort.restype = c_int

# int FECOM_GetPortPara( int iPortHnd, char* cPara, char* cValue )
fecom.FECOM_GetPortPara.argtypes = c_int,c_char_p,c_char_p
fecom.FECOM_GetPortPara.restype = c_int

# int FECOM_SetPortPara( int iPortHnd, char* cPara, char* cValue )
fecom.FECOM_SetPortPara.argtypes = c_int,c_char_p,c_char_p
fecom.FECOM_SetPortPara.restype = c_int

hport = FECOM_OpenPort(b'1') 
if hport > 0:
   FECOM_SetPortPara(hport,b'Baud',b'38400') 
   FECOM_SetPortPara(hport,b'Frame',b'8E1')
```

Comment: hmmm, ich change the first coll to the dll to hport = fecom.FECOM_OpenPort(b'3') and got ValueError: Procedure called with not enough arguments (4 bytes missing) or wrong calling convention

Comment: works with fecom = OleDLL('FeCom') how can I detect whether its an ole of windll or dll?

Comment: @bluelemonade Normally use `WinDLL` for `__stdcall` calling convention and `CDLL` for `__cdecl` calling convention. The latter is default. If the former, it will be indicated in the C header file, but may be hidden behind a #define. The error message you received indicates it is `__stdcall` so use WinDLL. `OleDLL` is also `__stdcall` but handles return values of `HRESULT`. So use WinDLL.

Comment: Now I have an function int FEISC_0xB0_ISOCmd( int iReaderHnd, unsigned char cBusAdr, unsigned char* cReqData, int iReqLen, unsigned char* cRspData, int* iRspLen, int iDataFormat )   how can I use unsigned char*  or int *